# Adding User Control instead of EditForm.aspx in designer

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, moss

Hello I am trying to add My user control instead of EditForm.aspx(using sharepoint 2007) I have added a new aspx page and registered my dll. But now I dont know how to proceed.
Also In my project I have one cs file which has following code.
public class SkillEditReg : WebPart
    {
        private Control _MyUserControl;

```
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
        _MyUserControl =
            this.Page.LoadControl(@"~/_controltemplates/MySkill/EditSkill.ascx");
        this.Controls.Add(_MyUserControl);

    }
```

An I tried to register it as feature I refered below link
http://fusionovation.com/post/2008/09/18/how-to-add-a-custom-user-control-to-a-sharepoint-page.aspx
I had put guid id in feature id.. and publictoken of assembly in element id.
And in contolId in designer I had put The usercontrol name..But nothing works..
Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so easy..All i did is hide the webpart of editform.aspx and went to the same page through browser it was emty then i edited the url and after EditForm.aspx?  I added toolpaneview=2. It opened in edit mode then i added my dll :)